# Objects on separated tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

Iv'e got 2 sets of objects in a form:

- txtDir
- cmbDir
- btnDir

and

- txtNews
- cmbNews
- btNews

How can i seperate them  on tabs, but keeping them in the same form?

Comment: We can certainly provide a programmatic solution, but it's much easier to just use the WinForms designer. Drag a `TabControl` widget onto your form and play around with it; it's quite intuitive. For example, you can click on a tab to select a different `TabPage`, and then drag controls onto it.

Comment: thanks, but how can i change the white color to the color of the form?

Answer (score 2):

Use TabControl to support tab based navigation